apache2.4, mod_jk, Jboss issue
at this time we have the following enviroment
Front Server A: is running under apache 2.2, mod_jk 1.2.30
Backend server B : running under Jboss 5.1.0
Everything is runing fine
We are trying to upgrade the front end server A and move to Apache 2.4, mod_jk 1.2.49, let us call it server C
once the new server is up we noticced the following:
1- if we remove server A and replace it with server C, everything looks ok and working as expected
2- when we restart the Jboss server on server B, we noticed that the Web server is sending the request to the management authentication page (JMX console) instead of the application one. and a popup to enter a username and password is shown on the page
We checked all setup and configuration and everything looks ok.
this is the configuration for workers.properties
# Define list of workers that will be used
# for mapping requests
worker.list=loadbalancer,status

# Define NodeA
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.nodeA.port=8009
worker.nodeA.host=192.168.0.242
worker.nodeA.type=ajp13
worker.nodeA.lbfactor=1


# Load-balancing behaviour
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=nodeA
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1


# Status worker for managing load balancer
worker.status.type=status

any help or support is really appreciated
